# How to redirect a ASP.NET Core MVC partial view after file download

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views

I have an asp.net core MVC partial view called ExportPagePartial that allows user to export a page from the system and downloads it. In the HttpGet controller action I show the partial view (as a Modal pop-up) to get user input.

**Modal Popup**

```
<a class="dropdown-item" asp-action="ExportPagePartial" asp-route-userId="@Model.UserId" asp-route-businessAccountId="@Model.BusinessAccountId" asp-route-projectId="@Model.ProjectId" asp-route-pageId="@Model.PageId" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalPlaceholder" title="Export page."><i class="fas fa-cloud-download-alt"></i> &nbsp; Export</a>
```

**Controller Get Action**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ExportPagePartial(string userId, string businessAccountId, string projectId, string pageId)
{       
    ExportPageViewModel model = new ExportPageViewModel()
    {
       // Set properties
    };

    return PartialView(nameof(ExportPagePartial), model);
}
```

Once the user hits Export button from the Modal pop-up partial view (which is a form submit action) the following HTTPPost action is correctly called.
In this action I have to get the file from the Web Api and then download it via the browser, however after download is complete i want to close the partial view. Once the download is complete the partial view is still visible.

The return action never works and partial modal pop-up view does not close
**return RedirectToAction(nameof(BlahRedirectAction));**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExportPagePartial(ExportPageViewModel model)
 {
            // Call Web API to get the file              
            string downloadUrl = "blah_blah_url";
            using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await WebApiClient.HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(downloadUrl, unprotectedExportInput))
                {
                    if (!httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    }

                    // Download the file now.
                    ActionContext actionContext = new ActionContext(HttpContext, ControllerContext.RouteData, ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor, ModelState);
                    FileStreamResult fileContent = File(await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType, httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
                    await fileContent.ExecuteResultAsync(actionContext);
                }

            // Redirect to main pain
            // The view never redirects and partial view is still visible
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(BlahRedirectAction));
 }
```

Comment: In what form is your partial view presented, similar to modal pop up? Can you provide comprehensive code for our reference?

Comment: @YongqingYu yes the partial view is presented as a modal pop-up, i updated the description to include more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> fileContent.ExecuteResultAsync(actionContext);

This is because when you download the file, `ExportPagePartial` has determined the return flow, and will not perform the `RedirectToAction`.

I suggest that you change the post method that triggers ExportPagePartial to **`ajax`** to achieve, so that you can successfully execute ExportPagePartial and after the method, redirect the page to what you want in js.

Here is a complete code of my demo based on your code:

```
  public class ExportTestController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult ExportPagePartial(string userId, string businessAccountId, string projectId, string pageId)
        {
            ExportPageViewModel model = new ExportPageViewModel()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Gender = "male",
                Name = "aaa",
                Number = "1231244"
            };
            return PartialView(nameof(ExportPagePartial), model);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ExportPagePartial(ExportPageViewModel model)
        {
            // Call Web API to get the file              
            string downloadUrl = "blah_blah_url";

              using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await WebApiClient.HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(downloadUrl, unprotectedExportInput))
                {
                    if (!httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    }

                    // Download the file now.
                    ActionContext actionContext = new ActionContext(HttpContext, ControllerContext.RouteData, ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor, ModelState);
                    FileStreamResult fileContent = File(await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType, httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
                    await fileContent.ExecuteResultAsync(actionContext);
                }

            // Redirect to main pain
            // The view never redirects and partial view is still visible
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(BlahRedirectAction));
        }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = null;
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("a").click(function () {
            var route = $(this).attr("href");
            $('#partial').load(route);
        })

        $("form").submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: $("form").attr('action'),
                type: 'Post',
                data: $("form").serializeArray(),
                success: function () {
                    //$("#ModalPlaceholder").hide();
                    window.location.href = "/ExportTest/BlahRedirectAction";
                }
            });
        })
    })

</script>
<a class="dropdown-item" asp-action="ExportPagePartial"
   asp-route-userId="1" asp-route-businessAccountId="1"
   asp-route-projectId="1" asp-route-pageId="1"
   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalPlaceholder" title="Export page."><i class="fas fa-cloud-download-alt"></i> &nbsp; Export</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="ModalPlaceholder" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <form asp-action="ExportPagePartial" method="post">
        <div id="partial">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

ExportPagePartial.cshtml：

```
@model ExportPageViewModel
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label">@Model.Id</label>
                <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" hidden />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Gender" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Gender" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Gender" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Number" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Number" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Number" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the test result:

[image]